# How can i change the names for parent and child theme in magento 2.

Tags: magento2

I am currently using porto theme in my site. I want to customize names of the themes(ie. porto and porto_child). I am aware i may not receive any updates on the theme, but i need to do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to change the name of the theme. Just left them alone is OK.

However, if you insist you need to do so, you just need to change the `registration.php` under `app/design/NewVendor/NewTheme` to the following:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/NewVendor/NewTheme',
    __DIR__
);
```

If your theme has `composer.json`, you need to change the `"name"` attribute too.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme name but I am not sure that it is safe or not. if you want to change it anyway then you have to change it in two files.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor_name/theme_name/registration.php

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'frontend/Vendor_name/theme_name',
__DIR__);
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendor_name/theme_name/composer.json

```
{ "name": "Your_Vendor_Name/theme-frontend-Your_theme_name",
"description": "N/A",
"require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.*",
    "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
},
"type": "magento2-theme",
"version": "100.0.1",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ]
}}
```